# how to find row number via searching string in table vba

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a table of several rows in my Word document. I want to search for a string in the table and when the string is found I want to add a new row below the string line. I wrote this code but its adding the new row after first row. I couldn't find where is the problem.

```
With ActiveDocument.Range
            With .Tables(3).Range.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Replacement.ClearFormatting
            .Text = "LPC STAGE 2.3"
            .Forward = True
            .Format = False
            .Wrap = wdFindStop
            .MatchWildcards = True
            .Execute
        End With
        Do While .Find.Found
            If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
                MsgBox .Cells(1).RowIndex
            End If
        Loop
    End With
    Set rowNew = ActiveDocument.Tables(3).Rows.Add
```

Comment: Your .find.found refers to Activedocument.Range. not the found range in table 3. Try moving the .Tables(3).range to the previous line  so that the .Find.Found refers to the found location in Table 3.  I'd also advise that you then read up on how to insert a row in a word table.  You might also find the .Range.Duplicate method helpful.

Comment: @freeflow Thanks, I changed **Activedocument.Range** to **.Tables(3).range**. It works for now.